# Simple file upload CKEditor

Tags: php, html, forms, ckeditor

I am trying to get a simple CKEditor file upload on my page but I am not really sure how to do that. I downloaded the CKEditor plug-in and added it to my page. Now I have an upload screen with all kinds of things you need to fill in. I only need it to be able to browse your documents for photos and use those.

My CKEditor code on my page:

```
<div class="box box-info">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">CK Editor <small>Advanced and full of features</small></h3>
    <!-- tools box -->
    <div class="pull-right box-tools">
       <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
       <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div><!-- /. tools -->
  </div><!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body pad">
    <form>
      <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="1" cols="80">
                        This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
      </textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.box --> 

<!-- CK Editor -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false; CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;</script>
<script>CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
  {
     customConfig: '/assets/plugins/ckeditor/config.js',
     filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/assets/plugins/ckeditor/plugins/browser/browse.php',
     enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
  });
</script>
```

how my config file looks like:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'insert', items: ['Smiley'] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Image' ]  }          
    ];

    config.autoParagraph = false;
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.fullPage = false;    
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)[*]{*};span(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*}';

    config.extraPlugins = 'youtube,ckawesome';
    config.fontawesomePath = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

    config.contentsCss = ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css','https://app.gratiswebshopbeginnen.nl/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'];

    // Se the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Make dialogs simpler.
    //config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload users Image with CKEditor

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="1" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
</textarea>

<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

So, from the above code we understand,

1. We are using ckeditor.js file
2. and  Initiating the ckeditor

These setups will show the ckeditor. Furthermore for the image upload we need one more settings

Open config.js file(/ckeditor/config.js)
and place the below code

> config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';

So, the config.js should look like this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
     config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
};
```

So, at upload.php the uploaded file will be catch able, here you can have your own php code to store the uploaded file into your server

So,when these settings works, the upload screen will looks like this

[image]

Comment: I eddited my question so you can see how my config file looks like now. Hope you can implant you idea with this code @ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: Perfect; Add `config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';` to your config file` and initiate ckeditor as I did; you will get the file uploader as like in the snapshot shown

Comment: I eddited the question and now it works but now I only want the 'upload' to be their and not the other taps. Do you know how to fix that? @ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: Replace Config.toolbar `config.toolbar = [{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Image' ]  }];` in config file

Comment: I mean in the upload function. I want the Bold and Underline ect to be their but what I want is: when you press the image button it will only display the "upload" as in your img @ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: Please create as another question

Comment: I did but no responses